# Logging MySQL interactive queries

Tags: mysql, debian

I have several people doing some database queries directly into some systems.

I would like to log to a secure syslog server all the queries done interactively/by hand, or failing that, all the queries done by using the `mysql` binary client.

I am using Debian Jessie, and Oracle MySQL 5.6.31

How could I achieve that?

Comment: Let's wait and see but I think you can't filter by client software and your only options are to log all queries or only slow queries. (Of course, when the server receives a connection it has no way to know whether you're typing in a keyboard or SQL was generated previously.)

Comment: Thanks @ÁlvaroGonzález ; I actually forgot that in the past I saw a possible solution, however at the time MySQL 5.7 was still in beta. I made it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you correctly spotted from MySQL 5.7 there is now the option to log to `syslog`.

Instead of creating an alias to the command as you have above, you could instead add `syslog` to a `[mysql]` section of either your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or a file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`

As in

```
[mysql]
syslog
```

This also allows for handy integration into `logwatch`.

Answer (score 2):

Starting in MySQL 5.7, the `mysql` command accepts the --syslog option. So I upgraded a test system to MySQL 5.7, and it works.
I will make an alias from `mysql` to `mysql --syslog`

From [MySQL 5.7 Reference Manual - mysql Logging](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-logging.html)

> syslog Logging Characteristics
>
> If the --syslog option is given, mysql writes interactive statements
>   to the system logging facility. Message logging has the following
>   characteristics.
>
> Logging occurs at the “information” level. This corresponds to the
>   LOG_INFO priority for syslog on Unix/Linux syslog capability and to
>   EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE for the Windows Event Log. Consult your
>   system documentation for configuration of your logging capability.
>
> Message size is limited to 1024 bytes.
>
> Messages consist of the identifier MysqlClient followed by these
>   values:
>
> SYSTEM_USER
>
> The system user name (login name) or -- if the user is unknown.
>
> MYSQL_USER
>
> The MySQL user name (specified with the --user option) or -- if the
>   user is unknown.
>
> CONNECTION_ID:
>
> The client connection identifier. This is the same as the
>   CONNECTION_ID() function value within the session.
>
> DB_SERVER
>
> The server host or -- if the host is unknown.
>
> DB
>
> The default database or -- if no database has been selected.
>
> QUERY
>
> The text of the logged statement.
>
> Here is a sample of output generated on Linux by using --syslog. This
>   output is formatted for readability; each logged message actually
>   takes a single line.
>
> Mar  7 12:39:25 myhost MysqlClient[20824]:   SYSTEM_USER:'oscar',
>   MYSQL_USER:'my_oscar', CONNECTION_ID:23,   DB_SERVER:'127.0.0.1',
>   DB:'--', QUERY:'USE test;' Mar  7 12:39:28 myhost MysqlClient[20824]: 
>   SYSTEM_USER:'oscar', MYSQL_USER:'my_oscar', CONNECTION_ID:23,
>   DB_SERVER:'127.0.0.1', DB:'test', QUERY:'SHOW TABLES;'

Comment: Instead of creating an alias you could add `syslog` to a `[mysql]` section of either your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` or a file in `/etc/mysql/conf.d/`

Comment: @Alasdair Please add an answer and I will accept it.