# Logging PostgreSQL interactive queries

Tags: postgresql, debian

I have several people doing some database queries directly into some systems.

I would like to log to a secure syslog server all the queries done interactively/by hand, or failing that, all the queries done by using the `psql` binary client.

I am using Debian Jessie, PostgreSQL 9.4 and 9.1.

How could I achieve that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/722221/how-to-log-postgresql-queries

Comment: @LandonKuhn Thanks. I am aware of the logging directives, however I only intend to log the commands done by hand/by operators, not the commands done by programs/software. The intention is identical to my other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37834849/logging-mysql-interactive-queries

Comment: Do the application and the interactive sessions connect as different users? You can set per-user overrides for many configuration variables with e.g. `ALTER USER ... SET log_statement = 'all'`.

Comment: @NickBarnes I would suggest you make that an answer. Whilst it is/was not my intention, it may work for my needs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are [a multitude of methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/config-setting.html) for setting configuration variables, with varying scopes.

As `log_statement` is a superuser-only setting, you can rule out all of the client-side options, and the server- or database-wide settings are presumably too broad for your case.

I believe this only leaves you with the per-user option, i.e.:

```
ALTER USER interactive_user SET log_statement = 'all';
```

Or if it makes things easier to manage:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET log_statement = 'all';
ALTER USER application_user SET log_statement = 'none';
```

Note that these settings are only applied on connection, so they cannot be triggered (or bypassed) via `SET ROLE` commands.

Of course, this all assumes that your application and your interactive users aren't sharing logins, but I don't think there's anything else with the right level of granularity.

Answer (score 1):

You can also add these directives to the config files normally located in `/etc/postgresql/{version}/main/postgresql.conf` or `/etc/postgresql/{version}/main/conf.d/my-overrides.conf` e.g.

```
log_connections = true
log_disconnections = true
log_statement = all
log_duration = true
```

You can also add `log_line_prefix` to supply more detail regarding the connection ([from the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/runtime-config-logging.html#runtime-config-logging-what)) in the form:

```
log_line_prefix = "string"
```

e.g.

```
log_line_prefix = '%m [%p-%l] [%c] %u %d %a '
```

where (for completeness) from the documentation the `printf` options are:

```
%a  Application name
%u  User name
%d  Database name
%r  Remote host name or IP address, and remote port
%h  Remote host name or IP address
%p  Process ID
%t  Time stamp without milliseconds
%m  Time stamp with milliseconds
%n  Time stamp with milliseconds (as a Unix epoch)
%i  Command tag: type of session's current command
%e  SQLSTATE error code
%c  Session ID: see below
%l  Number of the log line for each session or process, starting at 1
%s  Process start time stamp
%v  Virtual transaction ID (backendID/localXID)
%x  Transaction ID (0 if none is assigned)
%q  Produces no output, but tells non-session processes to stop at this point in the string; ignored by session processes
```